# Subset assignment of multidimensional array in R

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, indexing, assign

I am trying to assign rows of a 3D array, but I don't know how excatly.

I have a 2D index array where each row corresponds to the first and second index of the 3D array, and a 2D value array which i want to insert into the 3D array. The simplest way I found to do this was

```r
 indexes <- cbind(1:30, rep(c(1, 2), 15))
 rows <- cbind(1:20, 31:50, 71:90)

 for (i in 1:nrow(indexes)) for (j in 1:3)
    data[indexes[i,1], indexes[i,2], j] <- rows[i, j]
```

But this is hard to read, because it uses nested indexing, so I was hoping there was a simpler way, like

```r
data[indexes,] <- rows
```

(this does not work)

---

**What I've tried:**

[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11514964/how-to-index-a-multidimensional-r-array-dynamically) shows how to index the array (without assignment)

```r
apply(data, 3, `[`, indexes)
```

but this doesn't allow assignment

```r
apply(data, 3, `[`, indexes) <- rows #: could not find function "apply<-"
```

nor does using `[<-` work:

```r
apply(data, 3, `[<-`, indexes, rows)
```

because it treats rows as a vector.

Neither of the following works either

```
data[indexes[1], indexes[2],] <- rows #: subscript out of bounds
data[indexes,] <- rows #: incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

---

So is there a simpler way of assigning to a multidimensional array?

Comment: I answered something similar yesterday: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61801002/6574038, using `do.call`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `indexes` variable implies that `data` has first dim of 30, but `rows[30,j]` doesn't exist.  So your problem isn't well posed, and I'll change it.

The basic idea is that you can index a 3 way array by an `n x 3` matrix.  Each row of the matrix corresponds to a location in the 3 way array, so if you want to set entry data[1,2,3] to 4, and entry data[5,6,7] to 8, you'd use

```
index <- rbind(c(1,2,3), c(5,6,7))
data[index] <- c(4,8)
```

You will need to expand your `indexes` variable to replicate each row 3 times, then read the `rows` matrix as a vector, and then this works:

```
data <- array(NA, dim=c(30, 2, 3))
indexes <- cbind(1:30, rep(c(1, 2), 15))
rows <- cbind(1:30, 31:60, 71:100)

indexes1 <- indexes[rep(1:nrow(indexes), each = 3),]
indexes2 <- cbind(indexes1, 1:3)
data[indexes2] <- t(rows)  # Transpose because R reads down columns first
```

I don't think this is any simpler than what you had with the for loops, but maybe you'll find it preferable.

Comment: After reading your answer, I realised it could be done using `indexes2 <- as.matrix(merge(indexes, 1:3))`, I could use `data[indexes2] <- rows` directly. This is shorter and avoids transposing `rows`.

Comment: I'm not sure if I should post that as a separate answer, or if you could add it to yours so I can accept it.

Comment: That's a really nice solution.  Post it, I'll vote it up!

Answer (score 1):

After reading @user2554330's answer, I found a slightly simpler solution

```r
# initialize as in user2554330's answer
data <- ...
indexes <- ...
rows <- ...

indexes3 <- as.matrix(merge(indexes, 1:3))
data[indexes3] <- rows
```

---

comparison of `indexes2` and `indexes3` (using fewer elements):

```r
# print(indexes2)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    1    1    2
 [3,]    1    1    3
 [4,]    2    2    1
 [5,]    2    2    2
 [6,]    2    2    3
 [7,]    3    1    1
 [8,]    3    1    2
 [9,]    3    1    3
[10,]    4    2    1
[11,]    4    2    2
[12,]    4    2    3
```

```r
# print(indexes3)
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    1    1    1
 [2,]    2    2    1
 [3,]    3    1    1
 [4,]    4    2    1
 [5,]    1    1    2
 [6,]    2    2    2
 [7,]    3    1    2
 [8,]    4    2    2
 [9,]    1    1    3
[10,]    2    2    3
[11,]    3    1    3
[12,]    4    2    3
```